# Is there a way to include both WICTextureLoader and DDSTextureLoader without 'redefinition' errors?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to load a DDS texture. For that, I'm using `DDSTextureLoader11` provided by `DirectXTex`. I already am using another texture loader from the same library - `WICTextureLoader11`.

The problem is, I don't get errors with `WICTextureLoader11`, however I do get errors either when including only `DDSTextureLoader11`, or when I use both of them.

This is some of the errors I get when I include both or only `DDSTextureLoader11`:

`/WICTextureLoader11.cpp:51:17: error: redefinition of 'SetDebugObjectName'`

`/WICTextureLoader11.cpp:273:17: error: redefinition of 'MakeSRGB'`

`/WICTextureLoader11.cpp:747:17: error: no matching function for call to 'SetDebugObjectName'`

`/DDSTextureLoader.h:156:35: error: redefinition of default argument`

I first thought that it was because both `WICTextureLoader` and `DDSTextureLoader` contain same functions, so when including both they "overlap" (i.e. compiler detects redefinition).

I'm using a batchfile to compile my project, where I link against both `DirectXTex` and `DirectXTK`. I also tried to include `DDSTextureLoader`, but without success: I've read the GitHub page of the DirectXTK's `DDSTextureLoader`, where I include `<DDSTextureLoader.h>` that gives me a link error, which I guess is related to the incorrect call of the function `CreateDDSTextureFromFile`, so right now I'm trying to find a way to make the right call to the function.

**Edit:** no, it seems like I'm making the right function call. The wrong thing is that I'm trying to include `DDSTextureLoader.h`, but it also wants `DDSTextureLoader.cpp`. However, the errors occur when I include `DDSTextureLoader.cpp`, such as:

`'DDSTextureLoader.cpp': call to 'BitsPerPixel' is ambiguous -> 'DirectXTex.h'` or `'DDSTextureLoader' error: redefinition of 'SetDebugTextureInfo', previous definition in 'WICTextureLoader'`.

I think, what I need is to include the `.cpp` file, but somehow get rid of the errors.

**Edit2:** So far, I tried to get rid of DirectXTex (I don't remember why I even needed it), and I've included `WICTextureLoader.cpp` and `DDSTextureLoader.cpp`. I downloaded and built the DirectXTK library, then included `#pragma comment(lib, "directxtk.lib")`. Now, the weird thing is: when I compile with `Clang++`, it doesn't throw any errors (but the program crashes after a second-long gray screen), however when I compile with `cl` (through `vcvars64`), I get `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'directxtk.lib'`.

**Edit3:** Wait, I don't even know why I even need the `directxtk.lib`. So I removed it, and it compiles, but nothing works. I thought I needed that static library to resolve external symbol errors when trying to include the header (`XXXTextureLoader.h`), instead of the source (`XXXTextureLoader.cpp`).

**Edit4:** Wait,wait,wait. I think, I'm going crazy. Now, if I include only `WICTextureLoader.cpp` (and remove `DDSTextureLoader.cpp`), it gives me this error: `(directxtk.lib) mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease'`. I don't know why I did that, but I'm crazy now, I blindly brute-force my way through resolving this cursed issue. *Why can't I just throw both headers in my directory and just simply include them?* Is there a way to do so? What should I do? Why doesn't DirectXTK/Tex pages on GitHub give a step-by-step guide to how to use these things? *The examples drive me crazy!*

Please, help me resolve this what seems to be a simple issue.

**Edit5:** The last thing that I tried is to include `DDSTextureLoader.h` and `WICTextureLoader.h`, and use `directxtk.lib`, but it gives me these errors:

`directxtk.lib(DDSTextureLoader.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main-3dacd8.o`

`directxtk.lib(pch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main-3dacd8.o`

`LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

I don't use VS, so I don't know how to use `/NODEFAULTLIB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused once again with `DirectXTex` and `DirectXTK`.

I resolved the issue by:

1. Removing `DirectXTex`
2. Downloading `DirectXTK`
3. Running the `DirectXTK_Desktop_2019_Win10` solution
4. Changing the Build to `Release` and `x64`
5. Opening the properties
6. Finding the option `Runtime Library`
7. Choosing `Multi-threaded /MT`
8. Building the solution

In my source file, I include:
`#include <WICTextureLoader.h>` and `#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>`

I can now link to the generated static library `directxtk.lib`, without getting errors.

Plus. If there are people who want to use things like `/NODEFAULTLIB:library`, but you don't use `cl` or `Visual Studio`, you can use the `#pragma` directive in your source file like this:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT")`

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices for loading DDS and other image files with WIC:

- Use DirectXTex (the library)
- Use DDSTextureLoader/WICTextureLoader (the standalone versions)
- or use DirectX Tool Kit (the library).

There's no reason to use more than one of them in the same program, and it's going to conflict if you try. See [this post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/).

Unless you are writing a texture processing tool, or need support for the plethora of legacy DDS pixel formats, using *DirectX Tool Kit* is usually the simplest. The [tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for *DirectX Tool Kit* covers this pretty well.

The error you are getting indicates something much more basic to using Visual C++. The DirectXTex, DirectXTK libraries build using the recommended "Multithreaded DLL" version of the C/C++ Runtime (i.e. `/MDd` and `/MD`).

The error indicates your program is building with "Statically linked" version of the C/C++ Runtime.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/use-c-run-time)

You didn't mention what compiler toolset you are using other than "not VS".

See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for a bunch of 'basic device and present loop' samples. If you don't use VS, there are 'CMakeLists.txt' available on that site.

Comment: I did mention in my second edit that I compile with `Clang++` (that targets `MSVC`), but I also tried with `cl` (through `vcvars64`). I mentioned that I don't use VS to not be suggested to use nuget or directly load DirectTK/Tex libs to the solution, which I cannot do. The only thing I can do, is somehow link against the things that I need, using my Batchfile, either compiling with `Clang++/MSVC` or `cl`.

Comment: I have read the first link, and it seems like I want to use standalone versions, but the second link (tutorials) doesn't tell me how, it only gives an example of how to set it up using VS.

I can't understand the `C/C++ Runtime` part, what should I do? I also don't need examples that show how the thing works in VS, because I don't use VS, and I'm making what it seems to be right function calls, I just want to somehow include either the standalone versions without ting-tanglers and without getting errors, or link against DirectXTK and use it, also without getting errors.

Comment: Seems like standalone versions (`XXXTextureLoader11`) conflict with the `DirectTK`'s `XXXTextureLoader.cpp`. I guess I need to use just DirectXTK. The problem here is, as I'm including both 'XXXTectureLoader.h', I get errors of mismatching values (Static/Dynamic), that I don't know how to resolve. I tried to compile with `cl`, but it gives me totally different errors, such as `error C2678: binary '*': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'float'`. Compiling with `clang-cl` gives also a different error - cannot open some library, like `uuid`.

Comment: I resolved the issue, and posted the answer, thanks for the help.